# Lost my colour palette in Draw Something

Tags: draw-something

I have come back to play after a couple of hours and I have lost my colours. I now have red, blue, yellow, green, and black. I did have about 20 different colours I had bought which are now mysteriously gone. Where have they gone and will I ever get them back?

Comment: Have you closed (Terminated) your application and reopened it?  Your color unlocks should be linked to your account once you 'purchase' them.  Try logging out and in again.

Answer (score 15):

It seems to be a glitch with the game. The developers are aware of it and working on it. It would seem you can't really get them back for now, but the colours you bought are safe. I suppose you will get them back in an upcoming bugfix.

Veronica Belmont asked just about the same question to Joseph Alminawi and Garrett Peek, creators of Draw Something, on Twit.tv's Game On! aired on March 19.

Video: http://twit.tv/show/game-on/10  (approximately at 47:25)

Transcript

**Veronica Belmont**: I've been playing for a really long time, and I bought a lot of colour packs with the coins I've been winning, and they go away. I don't have any of my colours. I keep logging in and out, trying to get them back, and now they just won't come back at all and I'm very sad.

**Joseph Alminawi**: Your colours, your coins, your bombs, they're all safe. What's going on is that the game is just having a little difficulty grabbing and looking at your inventory, but we're on that right now and we should have this solved really soon.

**Garrett Peek**: All your coins and colours are safe; we have that all saved. It's just making the calls, since we're getting millions and millions of calls per second [it's causing trouble].